# I am running java runner calss and this throwing this exception error and all things were configured

Tags: bdd, rest-assured, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, rest-assured-jsonpath

[Please tell me what should I do to remove this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f92D.png)

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.cucumber.junit.JUnitCucumberOptionsProvider$JunitCucumberOptions does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Class uuidGenerator()' of interface io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser$CucumberOptions.
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.addUuidGenerator(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.parse(CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser.java:46)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:120)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

I add the i0.cucumber core dependency and also remove junit from the configuration because hamcrest is conflicting as Junit version is 4.1 and hamcrest using 1.3 version and in dependency it is using 2.2 and I update to old version of hmacrest but still facing this issue.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Can you [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve] please? People need to be able to reproduce your issue to debug it.